# How to reload rails fixtures into database during test running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, fixtures, database-cleaner

My legacy code is using DatabaseCleaner which wipes out database after each test being done. However it also wipes out loaded fixtures data and causes some tests which are using fixtures to fail, something like:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Exception: Couldn't find Country with 'id'=593363170
```

To make them work together, how can I rewrite all fixtures back to database during test? (I mean not rake tasks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Set `self.use_transactional_fixtures = false` 
at the beginning of the file before which you want to reload fixtures.

Or use `use_transactional_tests` in Rails 5.

Do not set it in `spec_helper` as it applies globally so conflicts with DatabaseCleaner.